# Inclusions between $L^p$ spaces.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

> **Theorem.** Let $\mu(X)<\infty$. Then $$1\le p \le q\le\infty\implies L^q(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)\subseteq L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu) $$

> **Def.** Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset, $f\colon\Omega\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ q.o defined. We said that the function $f$ is locally integrable in $\Omega$ if $f\in L^1(G,\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap G,\lambda)$ for all $G\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^n})$ with compact closure $\overline{G}\subseteq\Omega.$

In the definition $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We denote the set of locally integrable function with $L^1_{\text{loc}}$

I must prove that $$L^p(\Omega)\subseteq L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)\quad\text{for all}\;p\in[1,+\infty]$$

using the previous theorem.

Naturally $$L^1(\Omega)\subseteq L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$$

Now I don't know how to proceed. Could anyone give me a suggestion?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what $L^{1}_{loc}(\Omega)$ means?

Comment: It seems that your definition of $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$ includes being  $L^1(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurth yes, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $K\subset \Omega $ compact then $\lambda(K)<\infty$. Therefore, $(K,\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap K,\lambda)$ is a measure space with finite measure. Then take $f\in L^p(\Omega)$, since
$$\nu(E)=\int_E |f|^pd\lambda$$
is a measure and $K\subset \Omega$ then
$$\int_K|f|^pd\lambda\leq \int_{\Omega}|f|^p d\mu<\infty.$$
Therefore, $f\in L^p_{loc}$. Finally, since $(K,\mathcal{L}\cap K,\lambda)$ is a measure space with finite measure, $1\leq p$ and $f\in L_{loc}^p$, using your theorem with $q=1$ then $f\in L_{loc}^1$. So you get the inclusion
$$L_p\subset L_{loc}^1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of $L^1_{loc}(\Omega )$ seem strange. It should rather be $f\in L^1( K)$ for all compact $K\subset \Omega $. Anyway. Let $f\in L^p(\Omega )$. Then, if $K\subset \Omega $ is compact, $$\int_{K}|f|\leq \left(\int_\Omega |f|^p\right)^{1/p}\mu(K)^{1/q}$$
where $1/p+1/q=1$. Therefore $L^p(\Omega )\subset L_{loc}^1(\Omega )$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not strange, it's just more general. However I should use the theorem.